SCCM application deployment detection fails at first, but succeeds later
We have an application we deploy via SCCM. The deployment pretty much always succeeds, and the application will be installed on the target computer. However, the SCCM console commonly initially shows the deployment fails, with this error message:

The application was not detected after installation completed.

Later on, SCCM will finally detect the installation and show it succeeded, but the computer will be listed under the "Already Compliant" set.
This is odd: the error message indicates the issue is with the detection rather than, say, the installer returning the wrong result code. But the "Already Compliant" listing also indicates the detection does actually work, at least eventually.
To me this indicates a timing issue of some kind: either something for the detection is not actually ready, or perhaps the script is continuing without waiting for the installer to actually be done.

The detection method for the deployment is two parts:

A registry key, so we can be sure the app is at the latest version (often we are deploying an update for the same app already installed).
A file, because for some reason the uninstaller doesn't remove the registry key.

We haven't always used the file detection, but recent versions of the app will change the product name, exe, and guid each year (e.g. "MyApp2023" became "MyApp2024" on this year's first release, with associated file, registry, product guid, and installer updates). So now we also want to remove the prior versions, and adding the file detection lets SCCM correctly track when the removal is completed, because the uninstaller will actually remove the file.
I've noticed the issue is considerably worse since adding the file detection, but we've seen this without detecting the file, as well.

The installation method uses a short .bat script to run the app's installation program in silent mode and select the correct settings file for an embedded msi:
%~dp0MyInstaller.exe /s /v"/qn SETUPFILE=\"%~dp0MyAppSettings.dat\" "

The script also sets a separate registry key manually, but the above is the important step.

Considering this as a timing issue, I tried working around the problem by adding a delay to the end of the install script, as well as a manual test for the file in a loop:
Set TargetFile="C:\Path\To\MyApp.exe"

rem ... rest of install script

:WaitForFiles
If Exist %TargetFile% GoTo Finish
TIMEOUT /T 60 >nul
GOTO WaitForFiles

:Finish

But this doesn't seem to help; there are no changes to the behavior that I can see.

This app has been broken this way for a long time, and we put up with it. But it's annoying and does make things more challenging at app update time (2 to 4 updates per year).
What could be going on here? And how can I make this so SCCM will accurately report success/failure the first time?
One final observation is this app does install to the Program Files (x86) folder. So maybe there's some weird folder-redirection issue with the detection that is handled differently for the "already compliant" check?

Have you tried running the WMI method to trigger a software inventory after installation? Not sure if that is the missing link but it doesn't hurt to try it.
